# Install RabbitVCS for Thunar: package thunarx-python missing

Tags: 14.04, thunar, rabbitvcs

On 14.04 Trusty, trying to install RabbitVCS from the [RabbitVCS-PPA](https://launchpad.net/~rabbitvcs/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) results in the following error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install rabbitvcs-thunar 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 rabbitvcs-thunar : Depends: thunarx-python (>= 0.3.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: FYI, I've just uploaded v0.3.0 of the `thunarx-python` packages to the PPAs. This should no longer be an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, `thunarx-python` isn't in the PPA for Trusty.  I was successful installing the [deb package for Raring](http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu/pool/main/t/thunarx-python/thunarx-python_0.3.0-1~raring_amd64.deb) from [another PPA](https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/ubuntu/webupd8/+packages?batch=75&direction=backwards&memo=375&start=300) and setting the following symlink:

```
$ sudo ln -s "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0" "/usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0"
```

Now I could install the `rabbitvcs-thunar` package, getting the RabbitVCS menu items in the file menu and the context menu.